# Call a Procedure with parametes through DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-job

I am working on Oracle 11gR1

I have to call a procedure which accepts a CLOB as input parameter through a DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT procedure.

Here is my code for the same:

```
FOR i IN 1 .. lrec_resultset.COUNT LOOP

                    DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT (
                    JOB => job_num,
                    WHAT => 'execute_dsql('' ||lrec_resultset(i).sql_txt || '');');
COMMIT:
END LOOP;
```

The call to execute_dsql is not being made. I am not even getting any error message when I execute my PL/SQL block which contains this DBMS_JOB call.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
for i in 1 .. lrec_resultset.count loop

      dbms_job.submit (job  => job_num,
                       what => 'execute_dsql(mypkg.get_clob);');

      insert into mytbl values (job_num, lrec_resultset(i).sql_txt);

      commit;

end loop;

create package body mypkg
as
begin

  function get_clob
    return clob
  as

    v_clob clob;
    v_job  number;

  begin

     select sys_context('userenv','bg_job_id') into v_job from dual;

     select myclob
       into v_clob
       from mytbl
      where job_id = v_job;

     return v_clob;

  end get_clob;

end mypkg;
```

Comment: Note that just `'mypkg.get_clob;'` works fine. While `execute_dsql` is something custom and not public.

Answer (score -1):

you have a one single quote too much too much try :

```
WHAT => 'execute_dsql(' ||lrec_resultset(i).sql_txt || ');');
```

Comment: Actually, not enough single quotes!  Needs to be: `WHAT => 'execute_dsql(''' ||lrec_resultset(i).sql_txt || ''');');`